# terminating with uncaught exception of type Esri_runtimecore::Common::Out_of_range_exception

Tags: ios, objective-c, arcgis

While plotting the values on Arcgis, Arcgis is throwing below exception:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type Esri_runtimecore::Common::Out_of_range_exception: Out of range

I am trying to plot the coordinates as polygon on the map.
Here is my code snippet

```
AGSGeometryEngine* engine = [AGSGeometryEngine defaultGeometryEngine];
AGSSpatialReference *specailRefference = [AGSSpatialReference spatialReferenceWithWKID:3857];
AGSMutablePolygon *polyGon = [[AGSMutablePolygon alloc] initWithSpatialReference:specailRefference];

AGSPoint *minGPSPoint = [[AGSPoint alloc] initWithX:minLon
                                     y:minLat
                      spatialReference:[AGSSpatialReference wgs84SpatialReference]];

AGSPoint *minMapPoint = (AGSPoint*) [engine projectGeometry:minGPSPoint
                                    toSpatialReference:specailRefference];


[polyGon addPointToRing:minMapPoint];


AGSPoint *maxGpsPoint = [[AGSPoint alloc] initWithX:maxLon
                                               y:maxLat
                                spatialReference:[AGSSpatialReference wgs84SpatialReference]];



AGSPoint *maxMapPoint = (AGSPoint*) [engine projectGeometry:maxGpsPoint
                                      toSpatialReference:specailRefference];

[polyGon addPointToRing:maxMapPoint];
AGSSketchGraphicsLayer *gpsSketchLayer = [[AGSSketchGraphicsLayer alloc] initWithGeometry:nil];
[self.mapView addMapLayer:gpsSketchLayer withName:@"Sketch layer"];

AGSGraphic *graphic=[[AGSGraphic alloc]initWithGeometry:polyGon symbol:[self barrierSymbol2] attributes:nil];

[gpsSketchLayer addGraphic:graphic];
```

App is crashing is on `[polyGon addPointToRing:minMapPoint]` this line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have searched around for this issue and I found out that in case of **invalid coordinates** we get this error.
If we face this issue we need to check the input parameters.